# How to solve a runtime error in my VBA macro

Tags: vba, solidworks

i tried to insert an small table into my Solidworks drawing.
I record an makro but i get alway an error when it runs.

The error occures always in the second last line

```
myTable.Text(0, 0) = "123Test"
```

Here the makro (a little simplified)

```
Dim swApp As Object

Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Dim myTable As Object
Set myTable = Part.InsertTableAnnotation(0.229099360643554, 0.208027120622568, 2, 1, 1)
If Not myTable Is Nothing Then
   myTable.BorderLineWeight = 0
   myTable.GridLineWeight = 0
End If
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Detailelement6@Sheet 1", "ANNOTATIONTABLES", 0.20, 0.20, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Detailelement6@Sheet 1", "ANNOTATIONTABLES", 0.20, 0.20, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Set myTable = Part.SelectionManager.GetSelectedObject5(1)
myTable.Text(0, 0) = "123Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any tips pr solutions for me? Or do you need more Informations?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-select it after inserting.

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swDraw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
    Dim swTable As SldWorks.TableAnnotation
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swDraw = swModel
    Set swTable = swDraw.InsertTableAnnotation2(False, 0.22, 0.21, swBOMConfigurationAnchorType_e.swBOMConfigurationAnchor_TopLeft, "", 1, 1)
    If swTable Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Error creating table": Exit Sub
    swTable.Text(0, 0) = "123Test"
End Sub
```